# Show Bootstrap Alert success after post request Angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm new in Angular 9. I'm trying to make a http post request and then showing an bootstrap alert dialog to show if that the post request has been done successfully.

I've tried using the ***ngIf** directive, but the alert fades after the page refreshes.

*I'd like to show the alert div for about 3 seconds and then fades away*

**product.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Product } from './product';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { Category } from './category';

 @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class ProductsService
 {

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

   createProduct(productBody: any) : Observable<Product>
   {
     const urlEndpoint = 'http://localhost:3000/products';
     return this.httpClient.post<Product>(urlEndpoint, productBody);
   }
  }
```

**create-product.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Form } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductsService } from '../products.service';
import  Swal  from 'sweetalert2';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-create-product',
 templateUrl: './create-product.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./create-product.component.css']
 })
 export class CreateProductComponent implements OnInit
 {

   constructor(private productService : ProductsService) { }

   insertedSuccess : boolean = false;

   ngOnInit(): void
   {
   }

   addNewProduct(form : any, event : Event)
   {
     let newProduct =
     {
      id: 20,
      category_id: form.value.product_category,
      productName: form.value.product_name,
      description: form.value.product_description,
      product_image: 'form.value.path',
      price: form.value. product_price,
      is_available: form.value.product_available,
      rating: form.value.product_rating,
      reviews: form.value.product_reviews,
      color: form.value.product_color
     };

    this.productService.createProduct(newProduct).subscribe(data =>
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      Swal.fire("Good!", "Product Created Successfully", 'success');
    },
    error1=>
   {
     console.log("error");
   });
  }
 }
```

**create-product.component.html**

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" *ngIf="insertedSuccess">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  ARTICLE INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY!
</div>
```

As you can see, I've used the ngIf directive. As said earlier the div show just for a short time.
**I'd like to put the div after the post request has been successfully executed in order to show that the product has been inserted correctly**

**EDIT**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="addNewProduct(addProductForm, $event)" #addProductForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer01">Product Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Name" required name="product_name" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer02">Category ID</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="product_category" ngModel>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
       <label for="validationServer03">Description</label>
       <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Description" required name="product_description" ngModel>
       </textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label>Rating</label>
        <select class="custom-select" required name="product_rating" ngModel>
          <option selected value="">Choose..</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
         <label for="validationServer04">Product Color</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Color" required name="product_color" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
         <label>Is Available</label>
         <select class="custom-select" required name="product_available" ngModel>
         <option selected value="">Choose..</option>
         <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
         <option value="No">No</option>
       </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
         <label for="validationServer05">Product Price</label>
         <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Price" required name="product_price" ngModel>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
       <label>Reviews</label>
       <select class="custom-select" required name="product_reviews" ngModel>
           <option selected value="">Choose..</option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4</option>
           <option value="5">5</option>
         </select>
        </div>
      </div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Form</button>
   </form>
```

Comment: `alert fades after the page refreshes` -> why the page is refreshing and when the page refreshes then obviously alert fades away

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti if I set the insertSuccess variable to true, it should not fade, since the ngIf expression is true...The pages refreshes because the post request has been executed

Comment: So, what's happening in your case? is that fading away once the variable is set to true?

Comment: that's what my doubt. post request won't refreshes the page, but how it is getting refreshed in your case? can you share complete code present in subscribe?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti It is the complete code. I've not inserted the complete html because is pretty long. After i hit the submit button present in the form, the request fulfillss successfully and it refreshes the page

Comment: Then you have to prevent submit button's default behavior, so the page won't be refreshed. You can try `event.preventDefault()`. If you can post form html then it would easier to give suggestions to your issue

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti Here, I've added the html, and saying to prevent the default behaviour but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what was the problem.
Since I'm using VSCode and json-server and the WDS Auto Reload is enabled automatically, when I add a new product correctly it autorefreshes everything, making the alert disappear!

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing `<button type="submit"></button>` to `<button type="button" (click)="addNewProduct(addProductForm)"`.

The refresh must be caused by default browser submit behaviour.

Hope it helps. Please revert if not. thanks

Comment: Can you please try once removing the (ngSubmit) in form. Since you have posted the form value on button click, I suppose it is not needed.

Comment: No, Tried to remove the ngSubmit directive, added the preventDefault() method, changed the button from submit to button, but nothing works